# Getting Tor to randomly use various Country IP's per session

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration

I would like to have Tor use a different IP address in Canada every time I start or restart the application.

Is that possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 4):

Peter already suggested the FAQ entry: [Can I control which nodes (or country) are used for entry/exit?](https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq.html.en#ChooseEntryExit). So when your are using the Tor Browser Bundle navigate to the directory where the bundle lives. Within the subdirectory `Data/Tor` is the file `torrc`. You can open this file with a text editor and add the line:

```
ExitNodes {ca}
```

Save the file and restart Tor. Now Tor tries to use only canadian based exit nodes. However it might be the case that there is none in Canada. In the default setting Tor will just use one from another country. If you like Tor to fail if no canadian exit is available, add the option

```
StrictNodes 1
```

to your `torrc`.

In theory there might be a case where the geographical information is wrong. So the geoip file says IP address is in Canada while it is in the Democratic Republic of Congo. Here only an update of the geoip file helps. However I guess such a case doesn't happen very often.

In general I want to repeat Peters warning: *It is not recommended to use such a setting.*

Comment: If you're using the browser bundle you can also just go to the settings tab in Vidalia and add these settings.

Comment: @SamWhited Maybe you can explain where to find these settings. I didn't find it in my Vidalia version.

Comment: You can find them in the file where the poster mentioned them being then (they won't actually be in there, you'll have to add them). I don't actually use Vidalia, so I don't remember where the settings editor is by default. Maybe under Advanced?

Answer (score 3):

I think there is a [FAQ](https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq.html.en) entry that answers your question as far as Tor is concerned: [Can I control which nodes (or country) are used for entry/exit?](https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq.html.en#ChooseEntryExit).

Note that we recommend you do not use these!

I don't think the browser bundle exposes such config options, but you can probably just go to its directory and modify the torrc there.  Again, not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume by different IP address you actually mean a different path. Because obviously it's not healthy for the Tor network nor for its other users. So please don't try to do that.

And also limiting yourself to a specific country is not recommended as it will ruin your anonymity.

But if you mean a different path, that's what Tor already does. Every time you start the Tor Browser Bundle, it makes a new circuit with three random relays and the circuit stays alive for 10 minutes or less (depending on timeouts you get) and then it'll automatically switch to a different path.

If you want to force Tor to use a different path (that is, you keep getting timeouts), "New Identity" is the key.

Comment: As far as I see it, the question doesn't deal with the path itself, but only with the exit node. So your answer might be a bit misleading.