# Is it posible to choose what entry node you want to use?

Tags: security, deanonymization, guard-node

If I know of an entry node that I know the device running it is not malicious or being watched, do I have the ability to only use that as an entry point? And would this be potentially more secure than using a random node that could be run by a malicious party?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is somewhat similar to [Getting Tor to randomly use various Country IP's per session](https://tor.stackexchange.com/q/260/88).

If you know the name or fingerprint of the node, open the `torrc` and insert the following line:

```
EntryNode name
EntryNode $fingerprint
```

When you restart Tor it will use the entry nodes if avalaible.

Answer (score 2):

Using your own entry node (or a known good one) may be marginally more secure than using a random one but it also means that somebody targeting you only has to target your one, constant entry node to be able to correlate your traffic which is much more difficult if you are using random nodes.